# Disable WebPart's Title

Tags: web-part

I created a list and a new webpart for the list. I don't want to show title of the webpart. I clicked "Edit the webpart" and then I clicked Appearance and I selected "None" on the Chrome Type.

At first, it seemed using this method solved my issue. But when I refreshing page, webpart's title is shown again.

How can I disable the title permanently?

Answer (score 4):

You should click on `Apply` then `Ok` on the web-part properties window.

Also make sure page is published.

During editing the page, the title will get displayed, and we can't change that behavior.

Comment: the solve isn't permanently. When I refresh page, titles are visible again. And I add shown item limit, but item limit doesn't work, when I refreshing page.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: **Edit** the page in which you have added your webpart.

Step 2: In the web part property go to **edit web part**.

Step 3: In the **Apperance menu** select `None` for **chrome type**.

Step 4: Click on `Apply` and then `OK`.

I am using Sharepoint 2013. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS code to hide the web part title:

```
<style>
.ms-webpart-titleText{display: none;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while back. To solve that, do the following:

In the web-part, go to it's **Properties**, then go to **Appearance**. Here, in **Chrome Type** select **None**, this will hide both the title and border.

Example: [How to hide the web part title](https://www.ucdenver.edu/docs/default-source/atweb-documents/sharepoint-2010/working-with-web-parts-in-sharepoint-2010.pdf)

Hope it helps. I'm using SharePoint 2013.